# Using wordpress template tags within an array

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, php

A bit of a noob PHP question coming up.

I am trying to create a generic archive style view for my custom post types. Ideally I want to create one generic template that can be used for all post-types.

Currently I use this as my have_posts query to bring in all posts of 'custom-post-type'

```
<?php
 $args=array(
   'post_type' => 'custom-post-type.',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'caller_get_posts'=> 1
 );
 $my_query = null;
 $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
 if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
 while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
?>
```

What I want to do is swap out custom-post-type with the slug of the page so that whenever this template is assigned to a page, it will look for a custom-post-type of that name & list them.

Alternatively if you know of a better way of doing it - great!

Cheers,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rarst mentioned in the previous comment this is going to be patched in WP3.1

The template hierarchy is "archive-customposttypename.php".

[WordPress 3.1 template hierarchy](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Wordpress_Template_Hierarchy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$page = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$slug = $page->post_name;
```

PS I think next WP release will get proper custom post archives or something around that...

Comment: Sorry, can't get this to work.

Comment: Details? If you use this inside function don't forget `global $wp_query;`.